# Where to host SignalR when long-running service via WCF is backend

Tags: signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm sure that was a confusing enough title.

I have a long running Windows service dealing with things happening in the world. This service is my canonical source of truth for the rest of my system. Now I want to slap a web interface onto this so the clients can see what is actually going on. At first this would simply be a MVC5 application with some Web API stuff. Then I plan to use SignalR 2.0 and Ember.js to make this application more interactive and "realtime".

The client communicates with the Windows Service over named pipes using WCF. A client (such as a web app) could request an instance of for example IEventService, would be given a WCF proxy client, and could read about events through this interface. Simple enough.

However, a web application basically just exists in the sense that it responds to requests from the user. The way I understand it, this is not the optimal environment for a long lived WCF client proxy to raise events in, and thus I wonder how to host my SignalR stuff. Keep in mind that a user would log in to the MVC5 site, but through the magic of SignalR, they will keep interacting with the service without necessarily making further requests to the website.

The way I see it, there are two options:

1) Host SignalR stuff as part of the web app. Find a way to keep it "long-running" while it has active clients, so that it can react to events on the WCF client proxy by passing information out to the connected web users.

2) Host SignalR stuff as part of my Windows service. This is already long-running, but I know nada about OWIN and what this would mean for my project. Also the SignalR client will have to connect to a different port than where the web app was served from, I assume.

Any advice on which is the right direction to go in? Keep in mind that in extreme cases, a web user would log in when they get to work in the morning, and only have signalr traffic going back and forth (i.e. no web requests) for a full work day, before logging out. I need them to keep up with realtime events all that time.

Any takers? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of self-hosting as part of your Windows service is that you can integrate the calls to clients directly with your existing code and events. If you host the SignalR server separately, you'd have another layer of communication between your service and the SignalR server.

If you've already decided on using WCF named pipes for that, then it probably won't make a difference whether you self-host or host in IIS (as long as it's on the same machine). The SignalR server itself is always "long-running" in the sense that as long as a client is connected, it will receive updates. It doesn't require manual requests from the user.

In any case, you'll probably need a web server to serve the HTML, scripts and images.
Having clients connected for a day shouldn't be a problem either way, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you! The WCF layer is already there to communicate with a WPF client/monitor, so I might as well use that and get the benefits of MVC etc. The piece that was missing for me was the fact that SignalR will behave in a long-running fashion. Once more, thanks!